# What ide or tools use for magento formatting?

Tags: magento2, format, repair-tool

I've try netbeans and eclipse with psr2 format configuration but in magento files I've got:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $config
) {
    $this->config = $config;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

In those ides I've got:

1) Netbeans:

```
public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $config
)
{
    $this->config = $config;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

2) Eclipse:

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $config
)
{
    $this->config = $config;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

And other diff appearances. I'm not believing that not exist tools to format and magento team use PHP-CodeSniffer and then manually format if bug have been founded

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using PhpStorm and it's mostly recommended tool for Magento development. Also you can easily stetup PHP-CodeSniffer into PHP Storm. Here is the link for how to use PHP-CodeSniffer tool in PhpStorm [Using PHP Code Sniffer Tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/using-php-code-sniffer-tool.html)

Below is the PhpStorm formatting for your code

```
 /**
 * Class constructor.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context               $context
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $config
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $config
) {
    $this->config = $config;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

**Edited**

For formatting/fixing errors, either you can fix it manually or run the **phpcbf** command https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Fixing-Errors-Automatically

Comment: Php code sniffer you can use in netbeans and eclipce too. But tan you format by default. Not monualy?

Comment: Have tried phpstorm yes it can format like in magento for this case not have tested another.

Comment: You can fix it manually or run the phpcbf command.https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Fixing-Errors-Automatically

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my answer and would be appreciated if you accept it.

Comment: We have a new topic on [how to set up a Magento developer environment](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/build/optimal-dev-environment.html) as well as some info on [code sniffers](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ext-best-practices/extension-coding/working-with-arch-bp.html#use-the-phpcodesniffer-tool). Hope they're useful.

Answer (score 3):

For my self I've choose next:

1)I'm using netbeans so I've install http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/49042/php-cs-fixer

2) In magento 2.1 not know in prev versions in vendor/fabpot/php-cs-fixer/ we can find php-cs-fixer file this file I've set in pluging settings

3) Use php-fixer plugin command and all work like charm.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of missing people mentioning the [PSR1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) and [PSR2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) standards that [Magento follows](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/coding-standards/code-standard-php.html).

As a follow-up on Qaiser's answer, PhpStorm has predefined code styles which formats your code while you're writing it:

[image: Settings/Editor/Code Style/PHP]