# What is best code editor for Magento extension development?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, extensions, marketplace

I have developed few extensions using "Notepad++", "Sublime" or "Geany" code editors.

Although I am following the Magento EQP Coding Standard tool (https://github.com/magento/marketplace-eqp) to check the issues before submission on marketplace.

Generally I found the issues in technical review as below:

> End of line character is invalid; expected \"\n\" but found \"\r\n\"
>
> Spaces must be used to indent lines; tabs are not allowed
>
> Expected 1 space after comma in function call; 2 found
>
> Expected \"if (...) {\n\"; found \"if(...) {\n\"
>
> Opening brace of a class must be on the line after the definition
>
> Opening brace should be on a new line
>
> Line exceeds 120 characters; contains 131 characters
>
> No space found after comma in function call
>
> Closing brace indented incorrectly; expected 4 spaces, found 1

Is there any specific best code editor so I can reduce the warnings and errors counter while development?

Comment: You have to try PHPStrom, because is very professional and has so many features. At the beginning I was using Sublime, but after I start using PHPStorm I was very satisfied!

Comment: Please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142312/what-ide-or-tools-use-for-magento-formatting

Comment: I bought Phpstorm and I've never been happier with an IDE before. All products by JetBrains are just amazing. That's of course a personal opinion but I think that if you don't mind paying for an IDE Phpstorm is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You should use specific IDE like PHPStorm or NetBeans. PHPStorm is paid, Netbeans is free.